# Get the integer value inside a tensor tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a list of tensors, but i need to use the integer value that is saved inside each one. Is there a way to retrieve it without need to change eager mode?

Example test:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = tf.constant([1,4,5])
    np_array = test.numpy()
    integer_value = np_array[0]
    print(type(integer_value))
```

result: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

I need to get value 1,4,5 as integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Tensor.numpy()` method to convert `tensorflow.Tensor` to `numpy` array or if you don't want to work with `numpy` representation `Tensor.numpy().tolist()` converts your variable to python list.

```py
test = tf.constant([1,4,5])
np_array = test.numpy()
python_list = np_array.tolist()
integer_value = np_array[0] # or python_list[0]
```

EDIT:

if you turn off the eager execution you are left off with TF 1.0 behaviour so you have to make a `tensorflow.Session` to evaluate any `tensorflow.Tensor`

```py
tf.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()

test = tf.constant([4, 5, 6])
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
sess.run(tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer())
np_array = test.eval(session=sess))
```

Comment: I get this error while doing so: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`. In the test case works fine, but when i use it inside the project i get this error. Maybe it's because it's a Tensor instead of EagerTensor?

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I have edited the main post so that we get the same behaviour i get inside the project

Comment: I added code for disabled eager execution to the answer